# Generate private key from public key in ssh

Tags: git, ssh

Is it possible to generate private key if I have public key of ssh? I have public key copy with me but have lost private key. This is for my Git remote repository. Please help.

Comment: If it was, public key crypto would be completely useless. Think about it a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No:

- The public key is used to *encrypt* plaintext or to verify a digital signature.
- The private key is used  to *decrypt* ciphertext or to create a digital signature.

You need both, for the [asymmetric cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) to work. In your case, you need to regenerate a new public-private set, and register the public one on your Git repo hosting server.